# Are arrays better than lists in 2d games?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am making an inventory system and I have a choice to make inventory through lists and arrays. Which approach is better and why in C#? This inventory system is for a 2d Platformer in unity.

Comment: All what you need is [here](https://csharp-station.com/c-arrays-vs-lists/)

Comment: "which is better: a spanner or a screwdriver?" - any definition of "better" really depends on **what you're trying to do**

Comment: @MarcGravell spanner though :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .Net, a list is a wrap of an array. It has similar performance, but List has built-in methods to resize the array, which contains all entries of the list. If your arrays are never resized, not need to use List.